# Converting code from ES5 to ES6 and export is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql, babeljs

I'm getting the following error when trying to convert some GraphQL code from ES5 to ES6:

`_graphql2.default is not a constructor`

Here is the new ES6 code:

```
import GraphQLList from 'graphql'
import ConfigModel from '../../models/config'
import { configType as ConfigType } from '../types/config'

// Query
export default queryType = {
  type: new GraphQLList(ConfigType),
  description: "The configuration for the home 'page'",
  resolve: function () {
    const config = ConfigModel.find()
    if (!config) {
      throw new Error('Error')
    }
    return config
  }
}
```

The ES5 code looked like this:

```
var GraphQLList = require('graphql').GraphQLList;
var ConfigModel = require('../../models/config');
var ConfigType = require('../types/config').configType;

// Query
exports.queryType = {
  type: new GraphQLList(ConfigType),
  description: 'The configuration for the home \'page\'',
  resolve: function () {
    const config = ConfigModel.find()
    if (!config) {
      throw new Error('Error')
    }
    return config
  }
}
```

I'm guessing the transpiler is expecting this code to be a class but it's only supposed to be an object literal, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `import { GraphQLList } from 'graphql'` (`graphql` isn't a constructer, and never was; you used to instantiate `require('graphql').GraphQLList`)

Comment: Yup, that did it. Can I ask why that worked? I thought I only needed curly brackets if I wanted to destructure or rename my import? Why do I need it for one item?

Comment: Alternatively, you can (and should) use: `import graphql from 'graphql';` and `new graphql.GraphQLList(...)`, exactly what you did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially converted this ES5 line:

```
var GraphQLList = require('graphql').GraphQLList;
```

To this:

```
import GraphQLList from 'graphql'
```

You should be able to see the error here.

In the ES6 code, `GraphQLList` will be an object *containing all exports from that module* including one named `GraphQLList`.

So you can change your ES6 code from this:

```
new GraphQLList(ConfigType)
```

to this:

```
new GraphQLList.GraphQLList(ConfigType)
```

or, as a commentor mentioned, just do this:

```
import { GraphQLList } from 'graphql'
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about named imports, I thought the `import {ex1, ex2, ex3 } from 'blah'` syntax was only for renaming and destructuring, I must have skipped over that part in the docs :)

Comment: You should fix `new GraphQLList.GraphQLList(ConfigType)` by replacing it with `new graphql.GraphQLList(ConfigType)` and stating the appropriate import line.